# Unslider issue with positioning in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, unslider

I come to stakoverflow all the time, and I often find precious help in here!

I now have a question myself though, as I couldn't find any answer out there...

I'm using the Unslider script (http://unslider.com/), and I got it to work (even though I had a hard time doing so, but again, I got precious help browsing related questions here).

...however I see a small positioning problem in IE (I only have 9, but I also tested in an emulator, and it is showing the same problem):

On the first slide, I get a 1 px misplacing (on the right side of the slide, I get to see 1 px from the next image). This increases as the slides pass through (I have 32 slides)... so by the end of the slideshow the misplacement is something like 40 px or so...

Here's the testing url:
http://coresaocubo.pt/varchotel/html/galeria.html

My images have 900 x 400 px... and here's the CSS positioning I'm using:

```
.banner { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 900px !important; 
    overflow: auto; 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.banner ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.banner li { 
    list-style: none; 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.banner ul li { 
    float:left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 400px;
    -webkit-background-size: 900px auto;
    -moz-background-size: 900px auto;
    -o-background-size: 900px auto;
    -ms-background-size: 900px auto;
    background-size: 900px auto;
```

Other than this "glitch", I'm happy with the result, and I bet I'm making a rookie mistake somewhere, but I just can't figure it... please help?

Thank you so much!

Ana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this happens because IE rounds up percentages differently. If your images are always the same width you could override *li* element width, like this:

```
.banner li {
   width: 900px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your input... in .banner li it messed with the galeries dot navigation, however in .banner ul li, seems to work perfectly! So thank you so much for the insight!! :)